# Implementing MUL instruction in Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86-16, cpu-registers, multiplication

I need to multiply to numbers, but without using the MUL instruction in Assembly 8086.

For example:

```
mov bx, 2
bx -> bx * 41; code instead this line
```

Any Help?

Comment: 41 * 2 = 41 + 41 = 82, 41 * 3 = 41+41+41 = 123

Comment: Where are you stuck? Why can't you use the `mul` instruction? What other restrictions do you have?

Comment: probably a homework assignment to unstick base-10 brains (why cant you use mul).  we see this question every semester from many folks...in various forms...

Comment: n * 7 = n * 0b111 = n * (0b100 + 0b010 + 0b011) = (n*0b100)+(n*0b010)+n*0b001) = (n<<2)+(n<<1)+(n<<0);  all stuff we learned in elementary school.  except for shifting which is first semester programming class.  n*5 = n*0b101 = (n<<2)+(n<<0)   also n+n = n<<1   b = n+n, c = b+b,  which makes c = n<<2  and so on. if you can only add and not shift (which we saw that question this week).

Comment: (technically shifting works in base 10 as well, like base 2 you just pad with zeros, but you also have to do a multiply which is the difference between the two)

Answer (score 1):

### A simple solution uses repeated additions.

*Use one of the numbers as the counter and `add` that many times the other number to the result.*

What's important here is that the result needs to be dimensioned to **twice** the size of the original numbers. If both numbers are 16-bit, then the result must be 32-bit.

Next it's better to use the smallest of both numbers as the counter. This will reduce the number of iterations.

Also don't forget to *not* start the loop if the counter is zero. Then  obviously the product is zero.

```
 mov  bx, [Num1]
 mov  cx, [Num2]
 cmp  cx, bx
 jb   ClearResult
 xchg bx, cx        ;Puts smaller number in CX
ClearResult:
 xor  ax, ax        ;Clear 32-bit result
 cwd
 jcxz OK
AddAgain:
 add  ax, bx
 adc  dx, 0
 dec  cx
 jnz  AddAgain
OK:
```

Here the product is in `DX:AX`.

Answer (score 0):

To multiply a variable for a constant, you can, when it is convenient, decompose the constant into powers of 2; for example AX = AX * 320, 320 = 2 ^ 8 + 2 ^ 6.
Then make a shift to the left of the variable for each power and a sum. AX = AX * 320 becomes: AX = AX << 8 + AX << 6, but AX << 8 = (AX << 6) << 2.
If you want to multiply for a negative constant, you can apply same method but you must negate input before.

As said by Fifoernik, if you want to multiply a 16 bit register for a constant, you may need up to 32 bit result (furthermore you can have negative input-number); all the routines I've written are successfully tested and they are about three time more fast than IMUL (8086 assembly guides of Peter Norton):

Example A;  multiply AX for 41:

```
Function Mul41(Inp:Integer):LongInt; Assembler;

Asm

     Mov   AX,Inp

    {     DX:AX=AX*41; 41=32+8+1.
         BX, CX=TEMP}

{05} CWD             {DX:AX<-INPUT}

{02} Mov   BX,AX
{02} Mov   CX,DX

{02} ShL   AX,1
{02} RCL   DX,1
{02} ShL   AX,1
{02} RCL   DX,1
{02} ShL   AX,1
{02} RCL   DX,1      {DX:AX<-INPUT<<3}

{03} Add   BX,AX
{03} AdC   CX,DX

{02} ShL   AX,1
{02} RCL   DX,1
{02} ShL   AX,1
{02} RCL   DX,1      {DX:AX<-INPUT<<5}

{03} Add   AX,BX
{03} AdC   DX,CX     {DX:AX<-INPUT*(32+8+1)}

{41 CPU clock-cycles}

{128-154 CPU clock-cycles for IMUL RX}

End;
```

Example B;  multiply AX for -41:

```
Function MulM41(Inp:Integer):LongInt; Assembler;

Asm

     Mov   AX,Inp

    {     DX:AX=AX*-41; 41=32+8+1.
         BX, CX=TEMP}

{05} CWD             {DX:AX<-INPUT}

{03} Not   AX        {Because NEG AX before CWD ...}
{03} Not   DX        {... is wrong for AX=-32768 ...}
{03} Add   AX,1      {... it does a two complement of DX:AX}
{03} AdC   DX,0      {DX:AX<- -INPUT}

{02} Mov   BX,AX
{02} Mov   CX,DX     {CX:BX<- -INPUT}

{02} ShL   AX,1
{02} RCL   DX,1
{02} ShL   AX,1
{02} RCL   DX,1
{02} ShL   AX,1
{02} RCL   DX,1      {DX:AX<- -INPUT<<3}

{03} Add   BX,AX
{03} AdC   CX,DX     {CX:BX<- -INPUT*(8+1)}

{02} ShL   AX,1
{02} RCL   DX,1
{02} ShL   AX,1
{02} RCL   DX,1      {DX:AX<- -INPUT<<5}

{03} Add   AX,BX
{03} AdC   DX,CX     {DX:AX<- -INPUT*(32+8+1)}

{53 CPU clock-cycles}

{128-154 CPU clock-cycles for IMUL RX}

End;
```

Example 1B;  multiply AX for 320:

```
Function Mul320(Inp:Integer):LongInt; Assembler;

Asm

     Mov   AX,Inp

    {     DX:AX=AX*320; 320=256+64.
         BX, CX=TEMP}

{02} ShL   AX,1
{03} SBB   DX,DX
{02} ShL   AX,1
{02} RCL   DX,1
{02} ShL   AX,1
{02} RCL   DX,1
{02} ShL   AX,1
{02} RCL   DX,1
{02} ShL   AX,1
{02} RCL   DX,1
{02} ShL   AX,1
{02} RCL   DX,1      {DX:AX<-INPUT<<6}

{02} Mov   BX,AX
{02} Mov   CX,DX     {CX:BX<-INPUT<<6}

{02} ShL   AX,1
{02} RCL   DX,1
{02} ShL   AX,1
{02} RCL   DX,1      {DX:AX<-INPUT<<8}

{03} Add   AX,BX
{03} AdC   DX,CX     {DX:AX<-INPUT*(256+64)}

{43 CPU clock-cycles}

{128-154 CPU clock-cycles for IMUL RX}

End;
```

Example 2B;  multiply AX for 200:

```
Function Mul200(Inp:Integer):LongInt; Assembler;

Asm

     Mov   AX,Inp

    {     DX:AX=AX*200; 200=128+64+8.
         BX, CX=TEMP}

{02} ShL   AX,1
{03} SBB   DX,DX
{02} ShL   AX,1
{02} RCL   DX,1
{02} ShL   AX,1
{02} RCL   DX,1      {DX:AX<-INPUT<<3}

{02} Mov   BX,AX
{02} Mov   CX,DX     {CX:BX<-INPUT<<3}

{02} ShL   AX,1
{02} RCL   DX,1
{02} ShL   AX,1
{02} RCL   DX,1
{02} ShL   AX,1
{02} RCL   DX,1      {DX:AX<-INPUT<<6}

{03} Add   BX,AX
{03} AdC   CX,DX     {CX:BX<-INPUT*(64+8)}

{02} ShL   AX,1
{02} RCL   DX,1      {DX:AX<-INPUT<<7}

{03} Add   AX,BX
{03} AdC   DX,CX     {DX:AX<-INPUT*(128+64+8)}

{45 CPU clock-cycles}

{128-154 CPU clock-cycles for IMUL RX}

End;
```

Example 3B;  multiply AX for 100:

```
Function Mul100(Inp:Integer):LongInt; Assembler;

Asm

     Mov   AX,Inp

    {     DX:AX=AX*100; 100=64+32+4.
         BX, CX=TEMP}

{02} ShL   AX,1
{03} SBB   DX,DX
{02} ShL   AX,1
{02} RCL   DX,1      {DX:AX<-INPUT<<2}

{02} Mov   BX,AX
{02} Mov   CX,DX     {CX:BX<-INPUT<<2}

{02} ShL   AX,1
{02} RCL   DX,1
{02} ShL   AX,1
{02} RCL   DX,1
{02} ShL   AX,1
{02} RCL   DX,1      {DX:AX<-INPUT<<5}

{03} Add   BX,AX
{03} AdC   CX,DX     {CX:BX<-INPUT*(32+4)}

{02} ShL   AX,1
{02} RCL   DX,1      {DX:AX<-INPUT<<6}

{03} Add   AX,BX
{03} AdC   DX,CX     {DX:AX<-INPUT*(64+32+4)}

{41 CPU clock-cycles}

{128-154 CPU clock-cycles for IMUL RX}

End;
```

If you don't need a 32 bit result (only for positive numbers):

Example 1; multiply AX for 320:

```
{    AX=AX*320; 320=256+64.
 BX, CL=TEMP}

 Mov   CL,6
 ShL   AX,CL {AX<-INPUT<<6}

 Mov   BX,AX

 Mov   CL,2
 ShL   AX,CL {AX<-INPUT<<8}

 Add   AX,BX {AX<-AX*(256+64)}
```

Example 2; multiply AX for 200:

```
{    AX=AX*200; 200=128+64+8.
 BX, CL=TEMP}

 Mov   CL,3
 ShL   AX,CL {AX<-INPUT<<3}

 Mov   BX,AX

 ShL   AX,CL {AX<-INPUT<<6}

 Add   BX,AX

 ShL   AX,1  {AX<-INPUT<<7}

 Add   AX,BX {AX<-AX*(128+64+8)}
```

Example 3; multiply AX for 100:

```
{    AX=AX*100; 100=64+32+4.
 BX, CL=TEMP}

 Mov   CL,2
 ShL   AX,CL {AX<-INPUT<<2}

 Mov   BX,AX

 Mov   CL,3
 ShL   AX,CL {AX<-INPUT<<5}

 Add   BX,AX

 ShL   AX,1  {AX<-INPUT<<6}

 Add   AX,BX {AX<-AX*(64+32+4)}
```

Comment: Why don't you number your examples successively? "1,2,3"

Comment: The second example is wrong! 128 is 2^7 and so just 1 additional shift is needed, not the 2 that you wrote.

Comment: There's one problem that remains. What will happen when the number in `AX` is __not a very small__ number? (Say AX=210 in the 1st example) The shift operation will overflow without complaining, yielding a wrong product. That's why I wrote in my answer _"the result needs to be dimensioned to twice the size of the original numbers"_.

Comment: Ok. But this new version should be fine (save at least 67 CPU cycles compared to `MUL RX`).